# Make multiple edits with a single call to sed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to edit a config file. There are a few lines I'd like to change. I know that under Linux `sed -i` allows for in place edits but it requires you save to a backup file. However I would like to avoid having multiple backup files and make all my in place changes at once.

Is there a way to do so with `sed -i` or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can tell `sed` to carry out multiple operations by just repeating `-e` (or `-f` if your script is in a file).

`sed -i -e 's/a/b/g' -e 's/b/d/g' file` makes both changes in the single file named `file`, in-place.  Without a backup file.

`sed -ibak -e 's/a/b/g' -e 's/b/d/g' file` makes both changes in the single file named `file`, in-place.  With a single backup file named `filebak`.

Comment: Note that the sequence matters.  In the example command given above, all instances of the letter `a` are turned into `b`, and *then* all instances of `b` are turned into `d`.  You could do the same thing with `sed -i -e 's/a\|b/d/g' file`—turn all instances of either `a` or `b` into `d`.

Comment: and again for mac users `sed -i '' -e`

Answer (score 20):

As well as using multiple `-e` options, you can also separate sed commands in a single sed script using newlines or semi-colons.

This is the case whether that script is a one-liner on the command line, or a script file.

e.g.

```
sed -e 's/a/b/g ; s/b/d/g' file
```

The space characters around the `;` are optional. I've used them here to make sure the semi-colon stands out (in general, except for newlines separating commands, white-space between commands is ignored...but don't forget that white space within commands can be and usually is significant).

or:

```
sed -e 's/a/b/g
        s/b/d/g' file
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is `ex`, the predecessor to `vi`.  It is actually *the* POSIX tool of choice for in-place scripted file editing; it is extraordinarily more flexible than `sed -i` and arguably even more portable than Perl.  (If you stay outside of the Windows world, it's *unarguably* more portable than Perl.)

There is a relative dearth on this stackexchange of example commands using `ex`, at least compared with the plethora of example commands using `sed`, `awk` and Perl.  However, I myself have delved extensively into the [POSIX specs for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) and I've been beating the drum for it ever since.  I've written many answers using `ex` both here and on the vi/Vim stackexchange:

- [Delete 4 line above and below 5 line after pattern match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257697/135943)
- [How to delete everything after a certain pattern or a string in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257520/135943)
- [grep all the lines in a file and write line to a file from the pattern matching point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257472/135943)
- [How can I replace a character in all the .php files inside a folder on OS X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256170/135943)
- [How to append some line at the end of the file only if it's not there yet?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676)

Further reading:

- [Does Ex mode have any practical use?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2692/4676)
- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/4676)