# insert complex line before or after complex line

Tags: sed, awk, grep

i have file with complex text

```
    print("ERROR: passwords don't match")

password = hash_func(password.encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest()
```

i need to insert this text between them

```
with open('/etc/openvpn/clients/%s/login.txt' % username, 'w') as login_log:
    login_log.write('%s\n%s\n' % (username, password))
```

so it will be like this

```
 else:
        print("ERROR: passwords don't match")


with open('/etc/openvpn/clients/%s/login.txt' % username, 'w') as login_log:
    login_log.write('%s\n%s\n' % (username, password))

password = hash_func(password.encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Is there a pattern which can be used? Is it always ` print("ERROR: passwords don't match")` gollowed by `password = hash_func(password.encode("UTF-8")).hexdigest()`?

Comment: You Can edit the file with `vi` or `nano`, if you have Graphical interface then any text editor like `gedit` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat > user.inp << EOL

with open('/etc/openvpn/clients/%s/login.txt' % username, 'w') as login_log:
    login_log.write('%s\n%s\n' % (username, password))
EOL
sed -i '/ERROR: passwords/r user.inp' /root/add.py
fi
```

Comment: Why would you want to write that stuff into a file and then have `sed` read the file when `sed` can add those lines all by itself ?

Comment: i don't know how to do it with sed can you tell me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `vi`:

```
vi -c '/print("ERROR: passwords don'\''t match")/a\

with open('\''/etc/openvpn/clients/%s/login.txt'\'' % username, '\''w'\'') as login_log:
    login_log.write('\''%s\n%s\n'\'' % (username, password))
.' myfile
```

(This is all a single command.)

This will leave you with the file open in `vi` and the modification made, but the file not saved.  You can look at it and see if it's the way you want.

To exit and save the changes, type `:x` and press enter.  To exit and discard the changes, type `:q!` and press enter.

Any trouble, press `<Esc>` once or twice and then try `:q!` again.

---

The quoting on scripted edits can get atrocious very fast.  I recommend you just learn to use `vi` and open the file to edit it interactively; it will be much easier than puzzling out the quoting in the above command.

---

Much, much easier, if you already have the lines included in one file, and you want to insert them in the other file at a specific place, then you could tweak some [`ex` code I've already written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269193/135943) to do just that.