# Modifying existing file directly to substitute "foo" with "bar" ONLY for lines which contain "baz"

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have a food.txt file as follows :-

```
mangoes|foo|faa  
oranges|foo|faa  
chocolates|foo|baz
```

I am trying to replace *foo* with *bar* if condition baz is met. (would like to use a regular expression here b*z )
Currently using the sed command below, but this does not directly modify the existing file. I am also not able to use a regular expression (b*z).

```
sed '/baz/s/foo/bar/g' food.txt
```

Please suggest a way other than "sed" to modify the existing file directly.

PS : I tried `sed -i` but I would like to use some other command than sed.
I am using mobaxterm (OS - Windows)

Comment: Do you mean `b*z` (0 or more `b` followed by a `z`) or `b.*z` (a `b` followed by 0 or more characters and then a `z`)?

Comment: b.*z (0 or more characters). Dint know about b.*z regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual best tool for automated text edits is [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

Although it should be possible to call `ex` directly, I have found **in MobaXterm** that I have to call `vim -e` instead.

So, the best way to do this automated edit **in MobaXterm** (and which will also work on other *nix systems) is:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/b.*z/s/foo/bar/g' x | vim -es food.txt
```

To be fully POSIX compliant, it is only necessary to alter it to:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/b.*z/s/foo/bar/g' x | ex -s food.txt
```

However, calling the `ex` command may not work correctly on MobaXterm (it doesn't on my installation.)  Try the `vim -es` version of the command if the `ex` version fails.

Comment: Thank you. `ex -s ` is working for me on Mobaxterm. Can u please explain the code. I understand that `%s` stands for search  but not able to grasp the rest of it..

Comment: @jasmin, ironically enough, the %s *doesn't* stand for search but for "string."  :)  I'll add an explanation soon, but in the meantime if you start with [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269076/135943) and also read the links you will learn a fair bit more about `ex`.

Answer (score 7):

I see nothing wrong with using `sed` in this case. It's the right tool for the job.

Your command works well (on the given data):

```
$ sed '/baz/s/foo/bar/g' food.txt
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

Using a regular expression to match any string beginning with `|b` and ending with `z` at the end of the line (instead of `baz` anywhere on the line):

```
$ sed '/|b.*z$/s/foo/bar/g' food.txt
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

To make the change to the file (with GNU `sed`):

```
$ sed -i '/|b.*z$/s/foo/bar/g' food.txt
```

or (with any `sed` implementation):

```
$ sed '/|b.*z$/s/foo/bar/g' food.txt >tmpfile && mv tmpfile food.txt
```

---

You could also use `awk`:

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } $3 == "baz" { $2 = "bar" }; 1' file
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

or matching `^b.*z$` in the 3rd field,

```bash
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" } $3 ~ /^b.*z$/ { $2 = "bar" }; 1' file
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

... or [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`), here reading the input as a header-less CSV file that uses `|` as field delimiters:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --fs pipe put '$3 == "baz" { $2 = "bar" }' file
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

or,

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --fs pipe put '$3 =~ "^b.*z$" { $2 = "bar" }' file
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

The benefit of using `awk` or Miller is that it's easier and safer to match a pattern against an isolated field.  Miller has the added benefit of understanding CSV quoting rules.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the edit. The reason I didn't use `sed -i` was that it works very differently between GNU and BSD `sed`.  Just saying `sed -i script` will use `script` as a backup suffix with BSD `sed`. Doing `sed ... && mv` is safer and more portable.

Comment: Ah, fair point, that's very true. In any case, it [turns out](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303469/modifying-existing-file-directly-to-substitute-foo-with-bar-only-for-lines-w#comment532876_303470) the OP is using [mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) so I have no idea what `sed` flavor will be available. Feel free to roll my edit back.

Comment: @terdon No worries, I added extra comments instead.

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk` with `gsub()`:

```
awk '/baz$/ {gsub("foo", "bar")};1' food.txt
```

- Use any Regex pattern to match instead of `/baz$/`, if you want
- if the pattern matches, do `gsub()` to substitute desired strings

---

For inpace editing, Recent version of GNU `awk` (>=4.1.0) has inplace modification option:

```
awk -i inplace '/baz$/ {gsub("foo", "bar")};1' food.txt
```

Otherwise you can use `sponge` from GNU `moreutils` or use a temporary file:

```
awk '/baz$/ {gsub("foo", "bar")};1' food.txt >temp_food.txt && \
      mv temp_food.txt food.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|foo|baz

$ awk '/baz$/ {gsub("foo", "bar")};1' file.txt
mangoes|foo|faa
oranges|foo|faa
chocolates|bar|baz
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but i am getting an illegal statement error while executing the awk command.

Comment: @jasmin on what operating system?

Comment: Windows- using mobaxterm.

Comment: @jasmin um. Please [edit] your question and add that information then. That sort of changes everything since only specific tools and specific versions of those tools will be available to you.

Answer (score 3):

While I have no idea why you don't want to use `sed -i` which does exactly what you need, another option would be `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/foo/bar/g if /b*z/' food.txt 
mangoes|foo|faa  
oranges|foo|faa  
chocolates|bar|baz
```

The `-pe` means "print every line of the input file after applying the script to it.

And you can use `-i` to edit the file in place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g if /b*z/' food.txt
```

Also, note that the regular expression `b*z` means "match 0 or more `b` followed by a `z`. It will work here because `b*z` matches `bar` by ignoring `b` and `a` and just matching `z`. In other words, it will match any `z` since any `z` will be an example of 0 `b` followed by a `z`. I think what you probably mean to use is b.*z (a b followed by 0 or more characters and then a z):

```
perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g if /b.*z/' food.txt
```